# Parsec something like many1 but fail if ends

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm going through [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing) and I'm stuck on getting numbers to work properly. I want the following to parse a hex number

```
parseOct :: Parser LispVal
parseOct = do
        char '#'
        char 'o'
        x <- many1 $ oneOf "01234567"
        return . Number . fst . head . readOct $ x
```

This works if I give it `#o7` for example and gives me `7` as expected however it doesn't fail if I give it `#o78` instead it gives me `7`. It seems this is because of many1 which disregards anything once it doesn't match. Is there anything in Parsec that will enable me to get all the oct numbers but fail if it ever gets a non-oct character such as 8?

Comment: What should happen with the rest of the input, if anything that follows `#o` except `['0'..'7']` causes failure?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense in context. I would expect you to want to use all the digits in, e.g., `#o17`, which should parse to the number `15`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think indeed I need to think about what will follow rather than what will not, I will need to keep parsing to find the next param, sexp or eof.

Answer (score 2):

Use `notFollowedBy` to make sure no alpha-numerics follow the octal digits:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String
import Text.Parsec.Combinator

parseOct' :: Parser String
parseOct' = do 
  char '#'
  char 'o'
  x <- many1 (oneOf "01234567")
  notFollowedBy alphaNum
  return x

test1 = parseTest parseOct' "#o123"
test2 = parseTest parseOct' "#o1238"
```

E.g.:

```
*Main> test1
"123"
*Main> test2
parse error at (line 1, column 7):
unexpected '8'
```

Comment: I guess this is sort of what I am looking for, I think I need to explicitly state what can follow rather than what cannot (I think just ' ', ')' and eof), then it simply won't match if it's followed by something else, what do you think?

Comment: That can be handled by how you define the structure of an s-exp. When you write the rule for "an sexp is a sequence of basic terms separated by spaces surrounded by parens" parsec will expect a space, right-paren or eof after parsing any basic term.